# Selected options activate right subparsers

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have to invoke my script in this way.
`script.py multiple --ways aa bb -as abab -bs bebe`
In this case `-as abab` reffers to "aa" option from `--ways` parameter and `-bs bebe` to "bb" option.

And all chosed options should affect what "fulfill" method will be used.
If we chose 'aa' and 'bb' there should only be options '-as' and '-bs' not '-cs'.

```
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def fulfill_aa_parser(aa_parser):
    aa_parser.add_argument('--ass', '-as', type=str, required=True, choices=['abababa'])

def fulfill_bb_parser(aa_parser):
    aa_parser.add_argument('--bass', '-bs', type=str, required=True, choices=['bebebe'])

def fulfill_cc_parser(aa_parser):
    aa_parser.add_argument('--cass', '-cs', type=str, required=True, choices=['cycycyc'])

def fulfill_multiple_parser(multiple_parser):
    multiple_parser.add_argument('--ways', '-w', type=str, choices=['aa','bb', 'cc'], nargs='+', required=True)

def main(argv):
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='TEST CASE')
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='type')

    multiple_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
        'multiple'
    )
    aabbparsers = multiple_parser.add_subparsers()
    aa_parser = aabbparsers.add_parser('aa')
    bb_parser = aabbparsers.add_parser('bb')
    cc_parser = aabbparsers.add_parser('cc')
    fulfill_multiple_parser(multiple_parser)
    fulfill_aa_parser(aa_parser)
    fulfill_bb_parser(bb_parser)
    fulfill_cc_parser(cc_parser)
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    if args.type is None:
        parser.print_help()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Parsing this in this way:

```
    fulfill_aa_parser(multiple_parser)
    fulfill_bb_parser(multiple_parser)
    fulfill_cc_parser(multiple_parser)
```

will lead to parser always asking for '-as', '-bs' ,'-cs' and options in '--ways' will not affect this

EDIT : \
This is it looks when there is some thought put to it.
Just simply pass parser to this function

```
def fulfill_apple_argparser(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--apple_argument")

def fulfill_banana_argparser(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--banana_argument")

def fulfill_peach_argparser(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--peach_argument")

def many_fruits_parse(parser, progs=None, list_of_fruits=('apple', 'banana', 'peach')):
    progs = progs or []
    if len(list_of_fruits) == 0 or parser in progs:
        return
    fulfill = {'apple': fulfill_apple_argparser, 'banana': fulfill_banana_argparser,
               'peach': fulfill_peach_argparser}
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='subparser', dest=parser.prog)
    progs.append(parser)
    for fruit in list_of_fruits:
        secondary = [x for x in list_of_fruits if x != fruit]
        fruit_parser = subparsers.add_parser(fruit, help=fruit)
        fulfill[fruit](fruit_parser)
        many_fruits_parse(fruit_parser, progs, secondary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_subparsers` creates a special kind of `positional` argument, one that uses the `add_parser` command to create `choices`.  Once a valid choice is provided, parsing is passed to that `parser`.

With

```
script.py multiple --ways aa bb -as abab -bs bebe
```

`parser` passes the task to `multiple_parser`.  The `--ways` optional then gets 2 values

```
Namespace(ways=['aa','bb'])
```

Neither of those strings is used as a value for `aabbparsers`, and `multiple_parser` doesn't know what to do with '-as` or '-bs', and (I expect) will raise an error.

With:

```
script.py multiple aa -as abab
```

parsing is passed from `parser` to `multiple_parser` to `aa_parser`, which in turn handles '-as abab', producing (I think)

```
Namespace(as='abab')
```

Nesting as you do with `multiple` and `aa` is the only way to use multiple subparsers.  You can't have two subparses 'in-parallel' (e.g. 'aa' and 'bb').

Especially when testing it's a good idea to provide a `dest` to the `add_subparsers` command.  It gives information on which subparsers is being invoked.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will edit my initial post to explain how I figured it out. Many thanks